# Vertically align a floating img and h1 with absolute margin-left

Tags: html, css

I need to align an image and a heading vertically to the middle. Both need an absolute left margin.

For the last 3 hours I have tried to achieve both requirements, but I only get the objects properly aligned OR proper margins. How do I make the image and heading vertically aligned with absolute margins?

This is what I have in mind, but it seems I can only use float OR vertical-align with img.

```
.top {
    line-height: 50px;
}

.top img {
    margin-left: 15px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: left;
}

.top h1 {
    margin-left: 65px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline;
}
```

-

```
<div class="top">
    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/compatible_chrome.gif" />
    <h1>Text aligned vertically with the image + absolute left margin</h1>
</div>
```

See my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/76ftL/) experiments.

EDIT:
Here's an image of what I'm trying to achieve. The text has to be right next to the icon (absolute margin, not relative) and the icon + text need to be vertically centered.
[image: Absolute margin + vertically aligned]

The image size is not static which is why I need the text position to be absolute from the left edge.

Comment: you need to explain what the end result is.  Like do you want to have the text over the image or the text next to the image or what.. maybe a image to show us what you want the result to be.  Then we could better answer this question.

Comment: Do you want this? http://jsfiddle.net/76ftL/6/ when you want to use `vertical-align` remove the floating and use `display:inline-block` for the `h1` and the `img`. I'll leave this here: http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: Why arent't you considering the `position` & `top` properties in combination with margin?

Comment: Edited the question. Tyblitz: I don't want a static `top` because the image size may vary a bit. I already tried absolute `position` but that messed up the vertical alignment.

Answer (score 0):

your corrected code

**css**

```
.top {
    line-height: 50px;
}

.top img {
    margin-left: 15px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.top h1 {
    margin-left: 65px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

**css:**

```
.fragment {
border: 1px blue solid;
margin: 5px;}

.top {
background-color: #ccc;
width: 100%;}

.top img {
margin-left: 15px;
vertical-align: middle;}

.top h1 {
margin-left: 65px;
vertical-align: middle;
display: inline;}

.top2 {
background-color: #ccc;}

.top2 img {
float: left;
margin-left: 15px;
vertical-align: middle;}

.top2 h1 {
margin-left: 65px;
vertical-align: middle;}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="fragment">
<div class="top2">
    <table>
        <tr class="top">
            <td>
                <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/compatible_chrome.gif" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <h1>[X] Image and text aligned properly, [ ] 65px absolute margin-left</h1>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="top2">
            <td>
                <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/compatible_chrome.gif" />
           </td>
           <td>
               <h1>[ ] Image and text aligned properly, [X] 65px absolute margin-left</h1> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

EXAMPLE: http://jsfiddle.net/76ftL/7/

Comment: Ugh...tables for layout. Please don't recommend. Tables are for tabular data..which this is not.

Comment: I did consider tables (as a last resort), but then realized I can't use an absolute position for the text with a table. Thanks for answering though!

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute positioning on the image as follows.

**CSS**

```
.fragment {
    border: 1px blue solid;
    margin: 5px;
}

.top {
    background-color: #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    line-height:50px;
}

.top img {
    margin-left: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    -webkit-transform:translateY(-50%); 
}

.top h1 {     
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 65px;;
}
```

This is the 'magic' part

```
top:50%;
-webkit-transform:translateY(-50%);
```

Firstly we put the image halfway down the wrapper BUT translate it back up 50% of it's own height **regardless** of what that height is.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/76ftL/35/)